# Print a String to Matrix format column by column

Tags: c, arrays, string, matrix, dynamic

print the square matrix with the letters from given string vertically column by column with repeating letters separated by space.the size of the square matrix should be calculated based on the cells required to fill the characters in the given string.

Example:
Input(string):

HELLOWORLD

output(square-matrix):

```
---0  1  2  3

   0 H L R

   1 E O L

   2 L W D

   3 --O
```

----------------------------END OF QUESTION--------------------------

My c-program:

```
void main()

{

char arr[4][4],a[]="HELLOWORLD";

int i,j,n=0;

clrscr();

for(i=0;i<4;i++)

{

    for(j=0;j<4;j++)

    {

        if(a[n]!=a[n+1]){

        arr[j][i]=a[n];

        n++;}

        else

        arr[j][i]=' ';

    }

}

for(i=0;i<4;i++){

for(j=0;j<4;j++){

printf("%c",arr[i][j]);}}

getch();

}
```

i don't get the required output.Kindly help with the code.
Thanks.

Also help me how should i declare matrix arr[X][X] dynamically corresponding to user input string say "WELCOME" if it needs 3x3 matrix.

Comment: I recommend you read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger to step through your code line by line.

Comment: You should indent your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

void square_output(const char *mes);

int main(void){
    square_output("HELLOWORLD");
    puts("");
    square_output("WELCOME");
    return 0;
}

void square_output(const char *mes){
    char *str = malloc(strlen(mes)*2);
    char *cp = str;
    char *matrix;
    int side, exp_len, mat_size;
    //separate of duplicate letter by ' '
    while(*mes){
        *cp++ = *mes++;
        if(mes[-1] == *mes)
            *cp++ = ' ';
    }
    *cp = 0;

    exp_len = cp - str;
    side = ceil(sqrt(exp_len));//dim
    mat_size = side * side;
    matrix = malloc(mat_size);//1D array
    memset(matrix, ' ', mat_size);//initialize by ' '
    memcpy(matrix, str, exp_len);
    {   //print
        int c, r;
        for(c = 0; c < side; ++c){
            for(r = 0; r < side; ++r){
                if(r)
                    putchar(' ');
                putchar(matrix[r * side + c]);//This means matrix[r][c] in 2D
            }
            puts("\n");
        }
    }
    free(matrix);
    free(str);
}
```

Comment: @ BLUEPIXY help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45211559/finding-nth-power-of-integer-m-through-c-program

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically get the size you should be opting for `cmath` library and be using the `sqrt` and `ceil` functions

why `ceil`, in case your string length isn't a perfect square.

```
int dim = (int) ceil(sqrt(sizeof(a)/sizeof(char)));
char arr[dim][dim];
```

next iterate over the string, and use the `row` and `col` integer variables to iterate over your matrix

```
int row=0, col=0;
for (i=0; i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(char); i++) {
    arr[row][col] = a[i];

    col++;
    if (col>=dim) {
        col = 0;
        row++;
    }
}
```

if you are concerned about unused cell if the string length isn't a perfect square then initialize the matrix early on

```
for (i=0; i<dim; i++) 
    for (j=0; j<dim; j++)
        arr[i][j] = '.';
```

Comment: Since spaces may be inserted, `dim` calculations should use the length of the result.

Comment: int dim = (int) ceil(sqrt(sizeof(a)/sizeof(char)));
char arr[dim][dim];                                                                                              I get compilation error saying "constant value required" .                                      upon declaring char arr[4][4] instead of dim, it runs.  is there any way to run with char arr[dim][dim];?

Comment: @VineethMourya Use `malloc` if you can not use VLA.