# Finding nth power of integer m through C program without pow()

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, signed

C program to find nth power of integer m without pow().

Input:

```
m=3 n=2
output:
9.000
```

Tests to validate the program works as expected!

1. For negative M

> ```
> Input : -2  3
> output : -8.000
> ```

2. For negative N

> ```
> Input : 2  -3  
> output : 0.125000
> ```

3. For negative M and N

> ```
> Input : -2  -3
> output : -0.125000
> ```

However I am not getting the desired output

```
void main() 
{

    signed int m, n;
    int i;
    float p;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter the number and its power (exponent)\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
    p=1;
    if (n==0)
    {
        printf("%d raised to %d is: %f",m,n,p);
    }

    if (n>0)
    {
        for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
            p*=m;
        if(m>0)
            printf("%d raised to %d is: %f",m,n,p); 
        if(m<0) 
            printf("%d raised to %d is: %f",m,n,-p); 
    }

    if (n<0)

    {
        n=-n;
        for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
            p*=m;
        if(m>0)
            printf("%d raised to %d is: %f",m,-n,1/p);
        if(m<0)
            printf("%d raised to %d is: %f",m,-n,-(1/p)); 
    }
    getch(); 
}
```

Can u kindly provide the correct program for the test cases?

I can't declare `signed float` as it is giving an error.

Comment: For some specified input, what is the expected and actual output? Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger?

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Do you mind running the 3rd case again? Because [this](https://ideone.com/hm0UDX) says otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code for negatives is *incorrect*. You cannot just blindly *negate* the result when the base `m` is negative.
[image], but [image].  Also, you're not printing anything if `m` is zero!

And `int`s are signed by default so `signed int` is noise. `float`s are signed too; but here you could as well use a `double` for more precision. The return value of `main` should be `int`.

Therefore the fixed code would be (add nonstandard `clrscr`s and `getch`s to your taste ;):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    int m, n, i;
    double p = 1.0;
    printf("Enter the number and its power (exponent)\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);

    if (n==0) {
        printf("%d raised to %d is: %f",m,n,p);
    }

    else if (n > 0) {
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
            p*=m;
        printf("%d raised to %d is: %f",m,n,p); 
    }

    else { // n < 0
        n = -n;
        for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
            p*=m;
        printf("%d raised to %d is: %f", m, -n, 1 / p);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was surprised when he claimed that 3rd test case to validate passes. Was repeatedly doing the math in my head when I saw this answer :)

Comment: Thanks :)...Why use double? what is the precision it gives as u mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
void main() 
{

    signed int m, n;
    int i;
    float p;
    printf("Enter the number and its power (exponent)\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
    p=1;
    if (n==0)
    {
        printf("%d raised to %d is: %f",m,n,p);
    }

    if (n>0)
    {
        for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
            p*=m;
        printf("%d raised to %d is: %f",m,n,p); 
    }

    if (n<0)

    {
        n=-n;
        for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ){
            p*=m;
        }
         printf("%d raised to %d is: %f",m,-n,1/p);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Antti Haapala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45212013/2410359) well identified the errors in OP's code.

---

As an interview question relating to `pow()` substitute, certainly a solution that takes log2 N steps (as below) is preferable to one that takes N steps (OP's approach) where N is the exponent.

The key is to square the base on each iteration.
Using log2 N steps rather than N results in less error in the least significant digits.

With a negative exponent, simple invert the base.

Use `double` to provide to provide at least 10, typically 17, decimal digits of precision.

```
double powdii(int x, int y) {
  double z = 1.0;
  double base = x;
  if (y < 0) {
    base = 1.0 / base;
  }
  while (y != 0.0) {
    if (y % 2) {
      z *= base;
    }
    y /= 2;
    base *= base;
  }
  return z;
}
```